# What is meant by Bayesian Machine Learning in Regression?

Tags: bayesian, classification, posterior

Suppose I have a classification task and I assume a Gaussian discriminative model:
$$
P(y|x,\theta)= N(y|\mu_x,\sigma_x)
$$
where $x\in \{0,1\}$  are the features (1 for Company A, 0 for Company B) and $y\in R$ are the delivery time.
The book "Probabilistic Machine Learning: An Introduction" (Murphy, 2022) said that there are two ways to model the parameters: $\mu_x,\sigma_x$

1. Use MLE which solves the parameters as the empirical mean and variance respectively.
2. Do a Bayesian approach, utilizing $P(\theta|y,x)$

---

I fully understand the derivation and reasoning for using choice 1. However, I can't wrap my head around choice 2.

Suppose I use a full Bayesian approach and I used a Gaussian prior $N(\mu_x|\mu_0, \sigma_0)$ to model (assuming that $\sigma_x$ is given for simplicity):
$$
P(\theta|y,x,\sigma_x)=N(\mu_x|\hat{\mu},\hat{\sigma})
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}$ and $\hat{\mu}$ are linear weighted combinations of the prior parameters and the parameters that arrived from using MLE.

---

After computing, in a fully Bayesian manner, the parameters $\hat{\sigma},\hat{\mu}$ of $P(\mu_x|y,x,\sigma_x)$, how can I use these to solve the earlier prediction (regression) task ?

Comment: How is $y$ related to the classification task? What is the binary variable?

Comment: If $y$ is the label how can it have a normal distribution ?

Comment: @J.Delaney  sorry, I had mistaken $x$ for $y$. I had corrected the mistake thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to put a Gaussian prior distribution on a parameter in, say, a logistic regression?

Comment: @Dave yes, the same way for MAP but the book only said that this is being a fully Bayesian method. I am somehow confused by what constitutes a "Full" Bayesian method

Comment: @12775 If the target $y \in R$ then this is a regression problem, not classification. Are you sure this is what you mean ?

Comment: @J.Delaney I keep making mistakes, the $y$ represents the delivery time I confused it for classification since the examples are continual in the book. This question has somehow became unreliable. I'll edit it again  thank you very much

Comment: If you are doing classification you need a latent variable that captures class probabilities, you then compute posterior probabilities of that variable which gives you the probability of that class given the observed data. edit: it's still unclear from the question if this is regression or classification. If you meant regression, then the e.g. you get distribution of posterior mean (c.f. confidence interval in frequentist analysis).

Comment: @Lulu May I ask if the confidence interval can be obtained by $P(\theta|y,x)$ instead of the "frequentist" $P(y|x,\theta)$? If that is so, then that completely solves my problem, please make it an answer if you like to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Bayesian computation provides not just point estimates of the unknown parameters (as in "standard" regression) but a full *probability distribution* of those parameters.

If your model is

$$ y|x,\theta \sim f(x,\theta) $$

where $\theta$ represents the unknown parameters of the model, then the Bayesian calculation gives the posterior probability distribution of $\theta$,

$$ \hat P(\theta)  \equiv P(\theta | x,y) \propto f(x,\theta)\pi(\theta) $$

from which you can calculate the prediction for a new data point $x^*$, by integrating over all possible values of $\theta$ given its posterior distribution

$$ P(y^*|x^*) = \int d\theta P(y^*|x^*,\theta) \hat P(\theta) $$

which is again a *probability distribution* for $y^*$ (called the posterior predictive distribution).

You can use this distribution to calculate, for example, the mean of $y^*$ as well as intervals having a particular probability of containing $y^*$ ([Credible Intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval)) , as demonstrated for example by this plot (taken from this [blog](https://jessicastringham.net/2018/01/10/bayesian-linreg-plots/) )

[image]